# Usage of quotes in the letter writing

Tags: writing-style, quotation-marks

I have included this quote with single apostrophe within a sentence amidst letter writing. Is this allowed?

> Amidst his speech, I still remember his famous quote (saying): ‘Customer experience is the driving factor to choose right technology, It is not the technology that we force to sell in the market’, “iPhone” being one good example from this quote.

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Standard in the UK, quotes are generally enclosed in single quotes ('). In the US, it's double quotes ("). That said, I am from the UK and generally thing double quotes do it better, as there is then no confusion should single quotes be used within the quote (e.g. for abbreviation). So it's personal preference really.

The important factor involved is that whichever one you use, the OTHER one is used for nesting quotes within them.

Additionally, since you are using quotation marks you do not need "(saying)" in your text.

See here: http://www.eng-lang.co.uk/ogs.htm

Answer (score 0):

Always use double quotation marks in quoting speech. This applies in the UK as well!  However, if you are quoting within a quote, use single quotation marks. This differentiates the inner quote from the outer.

If you are writing a letter, you will not be using quotation marks as part of the letter itself, so if you quote someone, use doubles as normal.

Comment: OK, I will not use quotations in the letter, But How do I represent this point? just as simple sentence? uses doubles as normal? i did not get you.